# How do you create a table for user-input in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, user-input

I'm quite new to WPF and XAML and have been learning as I go. 
I am writing a program in which the user needs to be able to enter data into a table, with pre-defined columns, which is then later sent to a database. I am, however, unable to make a DataGrid that allowes for this behaviour -

I'm using a  - XAML is as follows:

```
<Grid MinHeight="100" MinWidth="600">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" 
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
            <DataGrid SelectionMode="Single" 
                      SelectionUnit="Cell" 
                      CanUserAddRows="True" 
                      CanUserDeleteRows="True"
                      IsReadOnly="False"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding SimpleCollection}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rownummer" Binding="{Binding RowNumber}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Navn på felt" Binding="{Binding FieldName}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Forretningsmæssig nøgle" Binding="{Binding BusinessKey}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Er der datoopl." Binding="{Binding ContainsTimestamps}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Er der koder, der oversættes via BAS" Binding="{Binding ContainsBASTranslatedCodes}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Metadata" Binding="{Binding Metadata}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Evt. bemærkninger" Binding="{Binding AdditionalComments}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
```

The class used in the binding:

```
 public class UserTable
{
    public int RowNumber { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string BusinessKey { get; set; }
    public string ContainsTimestamps { get; set; }
    public string ContainsBASTranslatedCodes { get; set; }
    public string Metadata { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalComments { get; set; }

    public UserTable()
    {
        this.RowNumber = RowNumber;
        this.FieldName = FieldName;
        this.BusinessKey = BusinessKey;
        this.ContainsTimestamps = ContainsTimestamps;
        this.ContainsBASTranslatedCodes = ContainsBASTranslatedCodes;
        this.Metadata = Metadata;
        this.AdditionalComments = AdditionalComments;            
    }

    public UserTable(int number, string name, string key, string timestamps, string translated, string meta, string additional)
    {
        RowNumber = number;
        FieldName = name;
        BusinessKey = key;
        ContainsTimestamps = timestamps;
        ContainsBASTranslatedCodes = translated;
        Metadata = meta;
        AdditionalComments = additional;
    }
}
```

The creation of the Collection:

```
private ObservableCollection<UserTable> _simpleCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<UserTable> SimpleCollection
    {
        get { return _simpleCollection ?? (_simpleCollection = new ObservableCollection<UserTable>()); }

        set { _simpleCollection = value; }
    }
```

(I am unsure where to place this - Have had it in the above mentioned class, and now in the .cs file that corresponds with the XAML)

Above code results in the following UI:

[image]

As you can probably see, the user is unable to enter anything into the table - There are no empty rows for data-insertion.
Does anyone have any idea about how to fix this?

Comment: what type `SimpleCollection` is? does it support adding new items?

Comment: ObservableCollection definitely can add items. do you set DataContext properly? are there any binding errors?

Comment: Please edit the code into your question. Also add some information on when/how the datacontext is initialized. The `set { _simpleCollection = value; }` is a potential issue, since it would allow to replace the collection without a change notification

Comment: Potentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169288/how-to-enable-newitem-placeholder-in-wpf-data-grid

Comment: I was definitely missing a constructor (which has been added above), but I still can't even see an empty row in the DataGrid - unless its all tied together, making sure the bindings Work, are probably a step too far ahead :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to add new rows to `DataGrid` you can create a `ViewModel` class and encapsulate your `ObservableCollection<T>` data collection in it, like i am going to show you.

for purpose of simplifying things let's say we have `User` model like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; } 
}
```

And let's create a simple view model class:

```
public class UsersViewModel
{
    public UsersViewModel() 
    {
        _users = new ObservableCollection<User>();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<User> _users;
    public ObservableCollection<User> User => _users; // C# 6 feature.
}
```

Now we need to create an instance of `UsersViewModel` class and assign it as data context to any element that is parent to your `DataGrid` in our case let's assign it to the `MainWindow` Grid `DataContext`, we can do it in XAML or in code behind:

```
<Window xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Namespace.In.Which.UsersViewModel.Lives">
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:UsersViewModel x:Key="viewModel"></local:UsersViewModel>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid" DataContext="{StaticResource viewModel}"></Grid>
    ...
</Window>
```

Or you can do the same in code behind like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mainGrid.DataContext = new UsersViewModel();
    }
}
```

After that you need to bind the `Users` property of `UserViewModel` to `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property:

```
<DataGrid ... 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"></DataGrid>
```

Now if you if you run your Application you will end up with an editable `DataGrid`.

You can set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `true` and the `DataGrid` will auto generate the correct columns type for your model.

I tested this steps on my machine and they work. Hopefully it helps you to solve your issue.

Comment: You have double `= =` signs in your viewmodel, other than that it looks like a good answer. Consider not providing a setter for the observable collection.

Answer (score 1):

For the user to be able to add items in the `DataGrid`, your `UserTable` class must have a default *parameterless* constructor defined.

So you will either have to define one or remove the other constructor that accepts parameters:

```
public class UserTable
{
    public int RowNumber { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string BusinessKey { get; set; }
    public string ContainsTimestamps { get; set; }
    public string ContainsBASTranslatedCodes { get; set; }
    public string Metadata { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalComments { get; set; }

    public UserTable() { } //<--

    public UserTable(int number, string name, string key, string timestamps, string translated, string meta, string additional)
    {
        RowNumber = number;
        FieldName = name;
        BusinessKey = key;
        ContainsTimestamps = timestamps;
        ContainsBASTranslatedCodes = translated;
        Metadata = meta;
        AdditionalComments = additional;
    }
}
```