# Blank Row missing when DataGrid has no data

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am working on WPF, I am designing a control that contains a datagrid, And everything goes well so far.

But something weird just happend: If I show one or more rows in the data grid, the datagrid shows at the end the blank row used to add new rows, as normal, BUT if there is no rows in the data grid, the blank row is not showed either!.

So, I need my datagrid to have always at the end the blank row whether or not data.

I have tried with the properties `CanUserAddRows` and `IsReadOnly` but as I said before it only works when there is one or more rows.

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean blank row?  Have a look at the answers on [wpf datagrid blank row missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466951/wpf-datagrid-blank-row-missing)

This basic set-up does display a blank row (even when bound ItemsSource has no data)

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Demo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    >
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <!--Must define columns if you need columns before bound collection has data-->
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Property"  Binding="{Binding Path=MyProperty}">   </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind

```
public class Data
{
    public Data(string value) { MyProperty = value; }
    public Data() { }  // Must have default constructor
    public String MyProperty { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{        
    List<Data> _items = new List<Data>(); 
    public List<Data> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
   }
```

Comment: Actually I had read that post but It was not useful to me, I still have the same weird problem

Comment: @Dante What is the datagrid bound to?  Can you post sufficient code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: right now I am retrieving data from a DataTable, what I do is this:`MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = myDataTable.DefaultView`

Comment: I have tried your code but I am still experiencing the same weird behavior :(

Comment: @Dante - Add you defining the DataGrid columns in your XAML?

Comment: No, Im not, Im trying to create them dynamically

Comment: @Dante - Sounds like you need to do something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/7321578/350550 then.