# WPF: DataGrid in RowDetailsTemplate has no empty new-row

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF `DataGrid` showing transactions with a `RowDetailsTemplate` containing another `DataGrid` showing the underlying subtransactions.  The subtransaction grid remains `"Collapsed"` until a row is edited in the transaction grid.  Then upon `BeginningEdit` the subtransaction grid is set `"Visible"` to allow editing them as well.  The transaction grid is bound to an `ObservableCollection<Transaction>` and subtransaction grid is bound to `ObservableCollection<Subtransaction>` (XAML shown at bottom).

This pretty much works as expected when displaying existing data.  However, while the transaction grid automatically displays an empty row for adding new transactions (image #1), I haven't been able to get the subtransaction grid to automatically add a new row (image #2).

I've tried several things including setting `CanUserAddRows="True"` (no improvement) and also adding directly to the subtransaction grid -- `subGrid.Items.Add(new Subtransaction(0))` -- which produced an expected error: `Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.'`

I have found that I can force an initial empty subtransaction row simply by adding a new object to the list before the subtransaction grid is displayed (image #3):

```
    private void BankDataGrid_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
    {
        var dg = (DataGrid)sender;
        // Show the details panel
        if (dg.RowDetailsVisibilityMode != DataGridRowDetailsVisibilityMode.VisibleWhenSelected)
            dg.RowDetailsVisibilityMode = DataGridRowDetailsVisibilityMode.VisibleWhenSelected;
        // Add a new item to create the empty row
        curTrans = (BankTransaction)dg.CurrentItem;
        curTrans.Subtransactions.Add(new Subtransaction(0));
    }
```

However, attempts to add a new empty row while in the subtransaction grid have failed despite that I can add to the list of subtransactions; i.e., the `curTrans.Subtransactions.Count` goes up.

```
    private void SubDataGrid_AddNewRow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Add an empty subtransaction to the bottom of the grid

        // This adds an item to the transaction -- the count goes up -- but no new row
        // appears in the subtransaction grid
        curTrans.Subtransactions.Add(new Subtransaction(0));
    }
```

Image #1 -- Transaction grid showing the automatic empty row added at bottom:
[image: Transaction DataGrid]

Image #2 -- Subtransaction grid with no automatically added empty row:
[image]

Image #3 -- Subtransaction with initial forced empty row:
[image]

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="BankDataGrid"
        Visibility="{Binding BankDataGridVisibility}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding BankTransactions}"
        RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"
        CanUserSortColumns="True"
        CanUserAddRows="True"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        Margin="10,50,10,10"
        RowHeaderWidth ="0"
        GotFocus="BankDataGrid_GotFocus"
        LostFocus="BankDataGrid_LostFocus"
        SelectedCellsChanged="BankDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged"
        AddingNewItem="BankDataGrid_AddingNewItem"
        InitializingNewItem="BankDataGrid_InitializingNewItem"
        PreparingCellForEdit="BankDataGrid_PreparingCellForEdit"
        BeginningEdit="BankDataGrid_BeginningEdit"
        CellEditEnding="BankDataGrid_CellEditEnding"
        RowEditEnding="BankDataGrid_RowEditEnding"
        CopyingRowClipboardContent="BankDataGrid_CopyingRowClipboardContent"
        >
        <DataGrid.CommandBindings>
            <CommandBinding Command="Cut" CanExecute="DataGrid_CanCut" Executed="DataGrid_Cut" />
            <CommandBinding Command="Copy" CanExecute="DataGrid_CanCopy" Executed="DataGrid_Copy" />
            <CommandBinding Command="Paste" CanExecute="DataGrid_CanPaste" Executed="DataGrid_Paste" />
            <CommandBinding Command="New" CanExecute="DataGrid_CanAddNew" Executed="DataGrid_AddNew" />
            <CommandBinding Command="Delete" CanExecute="DataGrid_CanDelete" Executed="DataGrid_Delete" />
        </DataGrid.CommandBindings>
        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Command="Cut" />
                <MenuItem Command="Copy" />
                <MenuItem Command="Paste" />
                <MenuItem Command="New" />
                <MenuItem Command="Delete" />
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Header="Test" Command="{Binding CustomContextCommand}" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ref" Binding="{Binding Reference}" Width="70" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Date" Width="100" SortMemberPath="Date" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat=\{0:MM/dd/yyyy\}}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Date}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Payee" Binding="{Binding PayeeName}" Width="200" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding Amount, StringFormat=\{0:N2\}}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100" >
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="?" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource statusEnum}, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Status}" Width="18" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Memo" Binding="{Binding Memo}" Width="220" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Subs" Binding="{Binding Subtransactions.Count}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="50" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="SubDataTemplate">
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <DataGrid x:Name="SubDataGrid"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Subtransactions}"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        CanUserSortColumns="True"
                        CanUserAddRows="True"
                        GotFocus="SubDataGrid_GotFocus"
                        LostFocus="SubDataGrid_LostFocus"
                        SelectedCellsChanged="SubDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged"
                        InitializingNewItem="SubDataGrid_InitializingNewItem"
                        PreparingCellForEdit="SubDataGrid_PreparingCellForEdit"
                        BeginningEdit="SubDataGrid_BeginningEdit"
                        CellEditEnding="SubDataGrid_CellEditEnding"
                        RowEditEnding="SubDataGrid_RowEditEnding"
                        CopyingRowClipboardContent="SubDataGrid_CopyingRowClipboardContent"
                        >
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Category1" Binding="{Binding Category}" Width="120" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Category2" Binding="{Binding Subcategory}" Width="120" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Class1" Binding="{Binding Classification}" Width="120" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Class2" Binding="{Binding Subclassification}" Width="120" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding Amount, StringFormat=\{0:N2\}}" Width="100" >
                                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                    <Style>
                                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                            </DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Memo" Binding="{Binding Memo}" Width="220" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Content="Add" Click="SubDataGrid_AddNewRow" />
                        <Button Content="Delete" Click="SubDataGrid_Delete" />
                        <Button Content="DeleteAll" Click="SubDataGrid_DeleteAll" />
                        <Button Content="Close" Click="SubDataGrid_Close" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: I can see why this is frustrating, for its a focus vs visibility issue  with a sprinkle of in-edit mode compounding it. But the example you gave is actual, its not viable in SO to reproduce by someone like myself. I suggest you provide an example (out of your project) editable solution in SO for all to run. Possibly that exercise might lead to a better understanding of the issue and a fix, if not it allows us to recreate and attempt an answer.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan -- yes, of course you are correct.  I will develop a sample and update this.  And I might discover how to get this to work in doing so. :-)

Comment: What I would do in this situation would be to create a custom `ListView` or even more plain an `ItemsControl` and override the the look/feel/styles and put in a double gridview which could do what you want out of the box per-se. The downside is wiring in the operations and what not...but you would be master of your own domain. ???

Comment: @ΩmegaMan -- I found the issue and updated the title to better reflect what was the real issue.  In trying to get the small sample working I found an article (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466951/wpf-datagrid-blank-row-missing/1637151#1637151) where the 2nd answer pointed out the requirement for a default constructor on the bound class.  So, my original question was really a duplicate of that article.  Rather than add an answer here, I think this question should now be deleted to reduce unnecessary noise.